# attached electrical junction box to furnace, how to protect wire

Tags: electrical, wiring, furnace

I'm connecting a handy box to a furnace, it's attached to the side.  There is a cutout on both the box and the furnace.  What is typically done in this situation to protect wires from the box to inside the metal enclosure of a furnace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably typical that nothing at all is done.. but you're right something should be done.

Try a chase nipple:

[image: chase nipple]

or a snap bushing:

[image: snap bushing]

(photos from homedepot.com)

Comment: I got a snap bushing, ... that kinda crappy on a metal box though? Or is that respectable?

Comment: if it fits the hole, doesn't fall out, and protects the wires from the sharp edges it's sufficient.

Comment: I'd use the chase nipple for this, it's a bit more robust

Comment: More specifically: chase nipple and lock nut.